# Use css only to accomplish this button layout

Tags: css

at first I thought it was easy, until I tried...

is there some god of css can help me lol

**but there is a premise, use css only and one html tag, no special character like &#9733**

I finished the outside, But I got one tsudo content only, how to set two stars and one word into that or optimize that(not a real button, just look like it will be fine, thaaaaaaaaaaanks for any help or any thought)

[image: use css only(and 1 html tag)]

i post what I did so far, and sorry for described it unclearly, It look like a button, not a  lol.

```css
#foo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 101px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px lightgrey;
}

#foo::before {
  content: "";
  color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 93px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(161, 161, 161);
  /* box-shadow: 1px 1px rgb(134, 134, 134); */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(230, 228, 228) 53%, rgb(199, 199, 199) 55%);
}

#foo {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rgb(209, 206, 206);
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use before or after pseudo selector to add text. Use CSS Entities or HTML Symbols to add stars.

Use multiple box-shadows to add multiple border styles

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

#foo:before {
  content: "★ CHECKOUT ★";
}

#foo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(230, 228, 228) 53%, rgb(199, 199, 199) 55%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 2px #0000001a, 0 0 0 8px #cbcbcb, 0 0 0 10px white, 0 0 0 12px #7d7d7d;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: forget to mention, sorry.... one html tag, no special character....

Comment: btw, your css was incredibly simple。。。 now I doubt what I learned

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea where I build the start using background (https://dev.to/afif/background-pattern-star-shape-194m)

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

#foo:before {
  content: "CHECKOUT";
  display:block;
  padding:20px 50px;
  --s: 40px; /* size */
  --m: 113px;  /* space */

  --v1:transparent,#fff 0.5deg 108deg,transparent 109deg;
  --v2:transparent,#888888  0.5deg  36deg,transparent  37deg;
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 54deg  at calc(var(--s)*0.68) calc(var(--s)*0.57),var(--v1)),
    conic-gradient(from 126deg at calc(var(--s)*0.5)  calc(var(--s)*0.7) ,var(--v1)),
    conic-gradient(from 162deg at calc(var(--s)*0.5)  0                  ,var(--v2)),
    conic-gradient(from 90deg  at calc(var(--s)*0.02) calc(var(--s)*0.35),var(--v2));
  background-size: calc(var(--s) + var(--m)) calc(var(--s) + var(--m));
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  background-position: 0 9px;
}

#foo {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background:  linear-gradient(rgb(230, 228, 228) 53%, rgb(199, 199, 199) 55%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 2px #0000001a, 0 0 0 8px #cbcbcb, 0 0 0 10px white, 0 0 0 12px #7d7d7d;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```